# Android Development - Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: android

So I'm dipping my toes into this area for the first time - i followed instructions to install the android SDK and eclipse plug in. I created a blank new android project and I get the following build errors:

```
[2011-01-08 16:34:55 - xxx]: Dxno classfiles specified
[2011-01-08 16:34:55 - xxx] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

I've googled the problem and tried to clean and rebuild, or hitting F5 on the project in the explorer but the issue remains. I've verified the build paths and the libraries to make sure only Android 2.3 is there but still get this issue.

I have also tried to load a sample project and I get the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this  - none of the above helped.

What i did was delete eclipse, download the latest one and reinstalled the ADT plugin and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

This problem happens when the java files in the Eclipse project are not compiled to class files. The message indicates that the Android SDK cannot proceed to convert these classes to dalvik format because it could not find them. To solve this problem:

1. Verify that the `src` folder is in your build path ( check under "Project Properties" ->  "Java build path" ). If this is not the case right-click on the src folder, go to "Build path" and click on "Use as source folder".
2. Verify that under "Project properties" -> "Builders" you can find "Java builder". If this is not the case close the project and with a text editor open the file `.project` present in the root folder of the project itself. Add under `<buildSpec>` the following lines:

   ```
   <buildCommand>
      <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
      <arguments></arguments>
   </buildCommand>
   ```

   After performing the actions described above, re-open the project and proceed to rebuild it by clicking on "Project" -> "Clean"

Comment: Adding src folder to the build path solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

Simply edit the "project.properties" file and comment the line:

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

to be like the following:

```
#proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

then clean the project. Hope this will export to APK successfully.

Comment: Unless you don't want to use proguard this is obviously not the right answer.  All the answer suggests is to comment-out the line which tells Eclipse where the proguard configuration file is.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is detailed [here](http://omer-muhammed.blogspot.com/2010/03/android-error-conversion-to-dalvik.html). Try these steps, and it should work out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: try to clean the project (Project -> Clean...). Eclipse will recreate the right bin directory.