# Android dalvik problem

Tags: android

Please i have different platforms installed. I just wanted to know what am supposed to do. If i develop with 3.0 platform, would those with a 2.2 be able to use my app??..

The second question which is the main question is I always get this error when i create android projects..
`[2011-05-16 16:32:21 - Hello World] Dx no classfiles specified
[2011-05-16 16:32:21 - Hello World] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1`

What do I do to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reports out there for that error (e.g., [this one](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5280384a481423e6#). All the solutions point simply to reload the project (select it in the tree at your left, and press F5).

Regarding the first question, unless you want to support Honeycomb-only features, then set up the api level to 8 (Froyo).

Eclair, Froyo and Gingerbread are android versions 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3 respectively (also referred in the documentation as API levels 7, 8 and 9). See the table [**here**](http://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html). **If you want to support just mobile phones, set your target to 2.1 or even lower**. That way you will be able to target most of the phones in the market. *Your app will also run in Honeycomb (3.x) devices*.

**Honeycomb has new features to support larger screen devices**, so if that is your main target, you might consider taking advantage of those features and drop cell phone support. **All will depend on what is your objective.**

Comment: I tried reloading but it didn't help..just printing out the same error :D Also I dont understand the froyo thingy. I want to develop for mobile for now so what sdk version should i use?

Comment: @DaMain see my updated response. Regarding your comment to Snicolas, below the xml interface, you will see two tabs: there you have the option to edit the xml text file directly.

Comment: thanks that cleared a lot up. Ok I have made my mind up to deve android apps for both mobile and tablets.. What level should i set it to. Also ii have changed the xml already but still isin't fixing the problem...Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: You can base your decision on this graph: http://www.androiddevelopmenttalk.com/news/android-os-usage-statistics-revealed-by-android-developers/ . Bottom line, go as low as you can, unless you need a specific feature not present in older api levels.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Am using a source online to learn and they use 2.3 so i would stick with 2.3. So about the error what do i do?? : i feel like crying now

Comment: The only other option out there is to reinstall eclipse... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634936/android-development-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1/4787865#4787865 . I can't help you more with this as I never saw that error before

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look at the minSdk and targetSdk features of a manifest file :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

This will help you target a android sdk version and precise what is the minimum sdk level that can run your app.

Regards,
 Steff

Comment: The manifest file isin't showing me the code and dats annoying. Rather its showing me an interface where i just enter values in textfields

Comment: I just tried it but instead it marked the manifest file as having n error or somefin(the yellow caution sign)

Comment: I have fixed it now. All i did was uninstall the plugins and also eclipse then re-install them and it was fine..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Developing for Honeycomb or non-tablet version of Android, is different in various things. Your 2.2 application should run correctly on a tablet, but if you want to optimize the graphical interface and use all the notification and other things included only in Honeycomb, then you must use the appropriate API. Until Ice Cream Sandwich is released, we have to develope two different application for the best result.

Regarding the error you get with android projects (I suppose under eclipse?) you'll find some detail at [this link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/22a92db16af2cb97), but if you follow all the instruction provided by google in the developers page, you'll be able to write and run your Hello World application.